# How to remove artefacts in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, discontinuity

Consider the following code

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to remove the "dragging" artefacts observed at the boundaries `x = 0` and `y = 0`? Naturally, the function is not defined here, but I am wondering whether I can get a cleaner plot. Is it possible to generally fix discontinuities in `Plot3D`? I am using version 14.0.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Exclusions -> "Singularities"]
```

[image]

To "close" the exclusions:

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"]
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely answer. Thanks! On a side note, why does Mathematica do that? Why does it attempt to plot at singularities by default, ending up with partially incomplete bands? Just curious about what `Plot3D` is actually attempting there.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, Sam.  Probably only the developers know why they chose this strange zigzag as standard.

Answer (score 10):

One possible way

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can play more with the values of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` if needed.

Note, `PlotPoints` seems to not be needed to change after adding `MaxRecursion`. Only `MaxRecursion -> 4` is enough. So this is enough:

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

Comment: Do you need `PlotPoints`?

Comment: @samwolfe  No, it is not needed. I was just trying different options. Will remove it.

Answer (score 6):

You can state the exclusions manually too:

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[x/y] + ArcTan[y/x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> {x == 0, y == 0}]
```

---

[image]